# How do I add a certain amount of numbers data together in gnuplot from a text-file?

Tags: linux, bash, server, webserver, gnuplot

I have a text-file that has generated values every second by a radiation monitor via a serial-controller. How do I add this data up to hours, days, etc. for gnuplot to plot? Preferably added via gnuplot rather than a separate file.

### For example:

```
30

32

28

30

32
```

Would be 5 seconds of data, **how can I combine this via the gnuplot .dat file to generate a graph that is over an hour/day rather than every second?**

I am new to gnuplot.

```
30

32

28

30

32
```

Generate a graph that is over an hour/day rather than every second.

Answer (score 1):

If a new line is generated every second, then plotting in bins of 60 will give counts/minute, plotting in bins of 3600 will give counts/hour, etc.

```
set ylabel "cts/minute"
plot "datafile" using 0:1 bins binwidth=60
```

"using 0:1" tells the program to generate bins from the line number and take the value of each line from column 1.  You have not said what you would like the x axis to show. Let's assume you want elapsed time.  You may also want to specify a plot style (points, lines, steps, ...) The commands would be

```
  set ylabel "cts/minute"
  set xdata time
  set xtics 60                 # one tic label every minute
  set xtics format "%tH:%tM"   # elapsed time in hours:minutes
  set xrange [0:*]             # start at zero elapsed time
  plot "datafile" using 0:1 bins binwidth=60  with steps
```

[image]